# Accessing data from different ViewModels

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, viewmodel, mvvm-light

I would like to access the data of different ViewModels in a single view.
But the DataContext is a completely different one (MainViewModel in the MainView). Is it possible to set the respective ViewModel for each window control?
Or is it better to create and reference the `ObservableCollection<Student> Students` only in the MainViewModel?

At the moment I would like to assign the property `Students` from the ViewModel `StudentViewModel` to this ComboBox.

**MainViewModel** (Setting the ApplicationViewModel as CurrentViewModel)

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            CurrentViewModel = ApplicationViewModel;            
            ShowStudentViewCommand = new RelayCommand(ShowStudentView);
        }


        public ViewModelBase CurrentViewModel
        {
            get => _currentViewModel;

            set
            {
                if (_currentViewModel == value) return;
                _currentViewModel = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentViewModel");
            }
        }


        private ViewModelBase _currentViewModel;
        private static readonly ApplicationViewModel ApplicationViewModel = new ApplicationViewModel();
        private static readonly StudentViewModel StudentViewModel = new StudentViewModel();



        public ICommand ShowStudentViewCommand { get; }        
        public ICommand ShowApplicationViewCommand { get; }


        private void ShowStudentView()
        {
            CurrentViewModel = StudentViewModel;
        }


        private void ShowApplicationView()
        {
            CurrentViewModel = ApplicationViewModel;
        }     

    }
```

**ApplicationViewModel  and StudentViewModel** (Loading data and creating the ObservableCollection)

```
public class ApplicationViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public ApplicationViewModel()
        {

        }
    }


 public class StudentViewModel : ViewModelBase
 {
        private ObservableCollection<Student> _students;

        public StudentViewModel()
        {
            DataStudentService dataService = new DataStudentService();
            Students = new ObservableCollection<Student>(dataService.GetAllStudents());
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Student> Students
        {
            get => _students;

            private set
            {
                if (_students == value) return;
                _students = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Students");
            }
        }
    }
```

**MainView.xaml** (Sets the CurrentViewModel to display)

```
<Window x:Class="Test.View.MainView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Test" Height="750" Width="700" 

        DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">

    <Grid>
        <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**ApplicationView.xaml** (This is currently displayed)

```
<UserControl x:Class="Test.View.ApplicationView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:Test.ViewModel"
             mc:Ignorable="d">
<Grid >


    <ComboBox
        TextSearch.TextPath=""
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Students}"
        DisplayMemberPath="Name"
        SelectedValuePath="Name"
        SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedStudent, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=SelectedStudentIndex, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
        IsEditable="True"
        Width="200"
        Margin="0,0,20,0"
        VerticalContentAlignment="Center" />



    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: As a note, it looks odd that you bind SelectedValue, SelectedItem and SelectedIndex at the same time. You would typically only bind one of them. It is also redundant to set `Mode=TwoWay`and `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on all your Bindings. While these settings are already the default values for the `Selected...` properties, they have no effect at all on the `ItemsSource` Binding.

Comment: @Clemens: Thank you for the hint, I use SelectedStudentIndex to reset the selection ("-1"). I'm trying to reduce the other parameters

Comment: A ViewModel can have properties of (sub-)ViewModels, no problem.

Comment: With SelectedValue only, resetting should work by setting Name to a non-existing value, e.g. null. Or without SelectedValue(Path), set SelectedItem to null.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: But how can i reference those properties?

Comment: Simple, by Name. You should add (an outline of) your ViewModel classes. I can't tell what your exact problem is now.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: I know this works with Caliburn.Micro but is this pure WPF behaviour?

Comment: Yes, notice that it is `Binding Path=Students` and not `Binding Property=Students`. Path means it can be a.b.c

Comment: unfortunately didn't work yet. i inserted the complete code. maybe the error is obvious

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:

**MainViewModel**

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public StudentViewModel StudentViewModel { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        StudentViewModel = new StudentViewModel();
    }
}
```

**MainView**

```
<ComboBox
DataContext="{Binding StudentViewModel}"
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Students, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
/>
```

**StudentViewModel**

```
private ObservableCollection<Student> _students;

public ObservableCollection<Student> Students
    {
        get => _students;
        set
            {
                if (_students == value) return;
                _students = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Students");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The most straight-forward solution would be to stick to the MVVM pattern by creating a collection and filling it with the data from the other class as you already mentioned. It's easy and everyone knows what's going on. Also, That way the *context* of the data stays in the same viewmodel and - if you change something - it also stays in that context. In your case that means you have to create a `ObservableCollection<Student> Students` and fill its content in the `MainViewModel`.

---

If that data has to be accessed from all over your application you should think about implementing a DataManager (a singleton, for example) rather than copying the data in every viewmodel.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Unortunately I have too many ObservableCollections<T>. I would like to keep all the same class elements in their respective viewmodel